# SSAS database memory usage?

Tags: database, memory, ssas

How can I determine how much memory each SSAS database is using?  The size is a property but the sum of the size isn't the same as the amount of memory each database is currently using.  Using tasklist, we can find out how much memory each SSAS instance is using (we have 4 per machine) - however I want to know how much memory per database is being utilized.  Any ideas how to obtain this information?

PS, I don't know if this question is better placed on DBA.SE or not.

Answer (score 0):

If Multidimensional not Tabular then install ResMon:
http://sqlsrvanalysissrvcs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ResMon%20Cube%20Documentation&referringTitle=Home